# Select all rows except those from today?

Tags: mysql

I'm selecting all rows except those from last 24hs. Instead I'd like to select those which are not from today. I'm already getting the day from a datetime column using DATE().

How can I change the query to do it?

```
select Date, DATE(Date) AS Day
WHERE Date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP said:

> I'd like to select those which are not from today

bfavaretto's solution:

```
SELECT Date, DATE(Date) AS Day
WHERE Date < CURDATE()
```

would answer the question:

> I'd like to select those which date is **before** today

To properly answer OP's question this query should be run (assuming date is a datetime because of the OP's cast, I'm casting it to a date field, but the cast is unnecesary if Date is actually a date field):

```
SELECT Date, DATE(Date) AS Day FROM aTable
WHERE Date(date) != CURDATE()
```

Comment: Though I could go with either method but I this is technically the correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's easier than you think:

```
SELECT Date, DATE(Date) AS Day
WHERE Date < CURDATE()
```

Comment: Beat me by a couple seconds. :) +1, and deleting my answer.

Comment: @KenWhite, that happens to me a lot!